# variable is changed without re-assignment in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in jquery code i pour an element in a variable .then by click **btn4** change the content of tag <**p**> .then i click **btn** to copy element by previous value 
but the variable also changed(assign to 2) whereas i don't reassign the variable .why? What can I do to prevent variable from changing?
also after click **btn** tag **p** by value 2 is removed from **div d1** why?

```js
let r = $("#d1 #p1");
$("#btn4").click(function() {
  $("#p1").html(2);
});
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#d2").append(r);
});
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}

#d2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn4'>btn4</button>
<button id='btn'>btn</button>
<div id="d1">
  <p id="p1">1</p>
</div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this, just add `.html()` to the end of your declaration for 'r':

```
let r = $("#d1 #p1").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

> i click btn to copy element by previous value but the variable also changed(assign to 2) whereas i don't reassign the variable .why? What can I do to prevent variable from changing? also after click btn tag p by value 2 is removed from div d1 why?

This is happening since you are appending the existing DOM node `$("#d1 #p1")` to `$("#d2")` and in the process moving it from exiting place `$("#d1")` to `$("#d2")`. You can resolve it by saving a `clone` of the node `$("#d1 #p1")` and using that to append like:

```js
let r = $("#d1 #p1");
let r2 = r.clone(); // Create a clone of current node with content

$("#btn4").click(function() {
  $("#p1").html(2);
});
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#d2").append(r2);
});
```

```css
#d1{background-color:red;width:130px;height:50px}
#d2{background-color:#ff0;width:130px;height:50px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn4'>btn4</button>
<button id='btn'>btn</button>
<div id="d1"><p id="p1">1</p></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case, the issue here is that he is holding a reference to the element in `r` variable, then he is appending the variable to `#d2` div. thats why `#p1` is moved (not deleted) to `#d2`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you are trying to perfom, but this line below refere to a DOM element;

```
let r = $("#d1 #p1").html();
```

By doing `$("#d2").append(r);` 
you move `r` element into the `$("#d2")` element. That why you don't see it again in `Div d1`.